# Profiling rendering time of SVG, Canvas for D3

Tags: javascript, canvas, d3.js, svg

I am rendering a line graph in D3 and I have implemented the rendering using both **SVG** and **Canvas** (because I heard that rendering on canvas gives better performance for static data).

I have tried to profile the time taken via Chrome inspection tools, and via JavaScript `performance.now()` shenanigans. However, both ways show that the function I wrote to draw the graph took only around 2000ms.

In reality, the graph takes around 1-2 minutes before it's rendered to the screen. How do I time how much time the rendering actually takes (short of using a stopwatch of course)? I am trying to improve the performance of the drawing function because 1-2 minutes is too long.

Comment: Give us your code please ... you've left us nothing to base an answer on. :-((

Comment: @markE I took the canvas code from: https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1550e57e12e73b86ad9e and the SVG code from http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3883245. From my profiling, the bottleneck does not seem to be in the pre-processing of my data so I suspect it's the graph rendering that's slow. Do note that I have around a million data points.

Comment: @Kaiido It becomes unresponsive for around 1-2 minutes, then the graph appears (pops up in a dialog box because I've programmed it that way, probably tangential to this discussion)

Comment: SVG retains your data points in it's `data` property while Canvas is "fire-and-forget". So SVG would be slower as it must use time and resources to load & save your data points. On my modest dev computer, canvas can draw 1 million lines in about 3500ms.

Comment: You can't profile rendering time yourself on browsers because it's asynchronous. Browser's inspection tools are the way to go.

Comment: @RobertLongson I've tried the browser profiling tool in Chrome inspector. The loading times reflected in the chart do not tally with the time I actually spent waiting though :(

Comment: @markE right, I've found Canvas to be substantially faster after more testing. The question is though, how do I measure the time spent drawing? Logging the time the function takes to run doesn't seem to be accurate at all.

Comment: Raise a Chrome bug with your testcase then.